# Compiler error when trying to print from struct

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, printf, member

My assignment is to, using structs, get input of info on employees, and output their pay.

It appears to run properly until I get to the end and try to `printf()` the calculated results.  The compiler tells me `[Error] request for member '*' in something not a structure or union`. (Replace * with ID, name, grossPay, netPay.)

Sorry if it's been asked; I'm still new to structs/pointers/etc, so I suspect it's a simple mistake.  It's just not jumping out at me. I looked through some of the previous questions but many are situation-specific.

```
// Matt Posey - PP #20

#include <stdio.h>

struct employee
{
    char ID[6];
    char name[20];
    float hours;
    float payRate;
    float grossPay;
    float netPay;   
};

int main()
{
    int j, i = 0;
    int employees;

    printf("This program computes pay.\n");

    printf("\nNumber of employees: ");
    scanf("%d", &employees);
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);

// Get data
    for (i = 0; i < employees; i++)
    {
        j = i; 
        struct employee j;

        printf("\nFor employee %d:", i+1);

        printf("\nID: ");
        gets(j.ID);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        printf("Name: ");
        gets(j.name);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        printf("Pay rate: ");
        scanf("%f", &j.payRate);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        printf("Hours worked: ");
        scanf("%f", &j.hours);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);

        j.grossPay = j.hours * j.payRate;

        if (j.hours > 40)
        {
            printf("Overtime!");
            float OT = (j.hours - 40) * (j.payRate * 0.5);
            j.grossPay += OT;
        }

        j.netPay = j.grossPay * 0.75;   

    }

// Output data

    printf("\n\nID     | Name                 | Gross Pay | Net Pay");
    printf("\n------ | -------------------- | --------- | -------");    

    for (i = 0; i < employees; i++)
    {   
        j = i;

        printf("\n%c | %c | $%7.2f | $%7.2f", j.ID, j.name, j.grossPay, j.netPay);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have an array or a list to store the `employee`s in.

Comment: Why `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);`?

Comment: `gets` is a terrible function. Never use it.

Comment: type of `j` is `int`. also `struct employee j;` is local scope (in for-loop) value.

Comment: "I have everything working" -- Not even close.

Comment: The `fseek()` function is just a quick way to clear the input buffer. I threw it in because the program was skipping over lines of input at runtime.

Comment: @chris Agreed. In fact, the bugs section of `man gets`, starts with "Never use gets()".

Comment: always include line number the error appears in.

Comment: @sp2danny thanks for the tip, I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with the question code...

1)

```
// Get data
for (i = 0; i < employees; i++)
{
    j = i;
    struct employee j;
```

The variable `j` is only visible inside the scope (ie braces) where it is declared.  Fix this by moving it to `main()''s scope:

```
int main()
{
    int j, i = 0;
    int employees;
    struct employee j;
```

Of course, this causes another problem it that there is already an `int j' defined.  Get rid of that:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int employees;
    struct employee j;
```

---

2) Next, you need `j` to be an array that can hold all the employees.  Unfortunately, you don't know (at compile time) how many employees the user will require.  So, just make a pointer to allocate some memory to later:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int employees;
    struct employee *j=NULL;
```

Let the user indicate how many employees, then allocate sufficient memory for the array:

```
 printf("\nNumber of employees: ");
 scanf("%d", &employees);
 fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);

 j = malloc(employees * sizeof(*j));
 if(NULL == j)
     {
     fprintf(stdout, "malloc() failed.\n");
     goto CLEANUP;   
     }
```

Then, put a 'goto label' just before the return statement:

```
CLEANUP:


    return 0;
}
```

In order to use the `malloc()` function, you will have to include another header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* Added for 'malloc()' */
```

---

3) Now get rid of the `j=i;` thing:

```
// Get data
    for (i = 0; i < employees; i++)
    {
       printf("\nFor employee %d:", i+1);
```

---

4) Now, everywhere `j` is referenced, reference it like an array:

```
    printf("\nID: ");
    gets(j[i].ID);
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    printf("Name: ");
    gets(j[i].name);
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    printf("Pay rate: ");
    scanf("%f", &j[i].payRate);
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    printf("Hours worked: ");
    scanf("%f", &j[i].hours);
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);

    j[i].grossPay = j[i].hours * j[i].payRate;

    if (j[i].hours > 40)
    {
        printf("Overtime!");
        float OT = (j[i].hours - 40) * (j[i].payRate * 0.5);
        j[i].grossPay += OT;
    }

    j[i].netPay = j[i].grossPay * 0.75;
```

And here too:

```
    printf("\n%c | %c | $%7.2f | $%7.2f", j[i].ID, j[i].name, j[i].grossPay, j[i].netPay);
```

---

5)  Get rid of the `j = i;` in `main()`:

```
for (i = 0; i < employees; i++)
{
    printf("\n%c | %c | $%7.2f | $%7.2f", j[i].ID, j[i].name, j[i].grossPay, j[i].netPay);
}
```

---

6) Fix the printf() format string.  It should be printing strings, not characters:

```
    printf("\n%s | %s | $%7.2f | $%7.2f", j[i].ID, j[i].name, j[i].grossPay, j[i].netPay);
```

---

Now the code is functional.

However, there is still some of the code that is risky.  For example, fgets() should be used (instead of gets()) [as indicated by chris & McLovin], etc.

```
    printf("\nID: ");
    fgets(j[i].ID, sizeof(j[i].ID), stdin);
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(j[i].name, sizeof(j[i].name), stdin);
```

And the report would be cleaner if there was an ending newline:

```
    printf("\n");

CLEANUP:

    return 0;
}
```

And as indicated by Ed Heal, this line is not needed:

```
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
```

[**SPOILER**](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/24836186_compiler-error-when-trying-to-print-from-struct.c)

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to explain that.

I took out the `fseek()` like you suggested, but it still skipped over lines of input so I put them back in.

Also, when printing the output, it's adding a new line after the first `%s` which throws off the table. Maybe it's my compiler? Seems like it's still recording an extra carriage return somewhere. I will investigate further.

Comment: Got it. Took out the `fseek()` commands and put in `strtok(j[i].ID, "\n");`, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a name "name of a variable" twice.

First you say there's an int called `j`, then you stay there is a `struct employee` called `j`.  Rename one or the other.

```
   int j, i = 0;
   (and much later)
   j = i; 
   struct employee j;
```